# lamda system in quantum optics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

why is lamda type configuration  prefered over other type of configurations, while studying CPT & EIT. Is it easy to prepare this configuration in lab or it has got any other technical advantages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: the $\Lambda$ system is very interesting in practice since there is only one highly excited (hence, unstable by spontaneous emission) state, which means that you can create long-lived superposition states with the other two states. This does not occur in other (e.g. ladder) configurations.

Second: it is a very natural system that can be approximately found in many atomic and molecular systems.